# Broken RAID6 on Asustor Appliance

Tags: linux, raid, mount

I have brand new Asustor AS7008T NAS with 8 X 8TB HDD, in RAID6.
After writing about 20TB, The volume become unavailable.

After:

```
mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md1 \
/dev/sdc4 /dev/sdf4 /dev/sde4 /dev/sdh4 \
/dev/hdg4 /dev/sdb4 /dev/sda4 /dev/sdd4
```

I get:

```
root@BigBrain:/ # mdadm --detail /dev/md1
/dev/md1:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Mon Sep 25 13:10:01 2017
     Raid Level : raid6
     Array Size : 46856632320 (44685.97 GiB 47981.19 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7809438720 (7447.66 GiB 7996.87 GB)
   Raid Devices : 8
  Total Devices : 8
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Wed Dec 20 19:23:52 2017
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 8
Working Devices : 8
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

           Name : AS7008T-83CC:1
           UUID : 2ac9c9a2:e2d004ca:2820dd2b:860c4a30
         Events : 733

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       36        0      active sync   /dev/sdc4
       1       8       52        1      active sync   /dev/sdd4
       2       8        4        2      active sync   /dev/sda4
       3       8       20        3      active sync   /dev/sdb4
       4       8      100        4      active sync   /dev/sdg4
       5       8      116        5      active sync   /dev/sdh4
       6       8       68        6      active sync   /dev/sde4
       7       8       84        7      active sync   /dev/sdf4
```

I can't mount `md1`:

```
root@BigBrain:/ # mount /dev/md1 /volume1
mount: mounting /dev/md1 on /volume1 failed: Invalid argument
```

Any advise will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your outputs don't really shed any light on the subject.  Could you add the output of fdisk -l /dev/md1 to your Q's?  On Debian, I check "cat /proc/mdstat" to check array build state, could you also add that equivalent information as well?

Comment: root@BigBrain:/ # fdisk -l /dev/md1
fdisk: device has more than 2^32 sectors, can't use all of them

Disk /dev/md1: 2199.0 GB, 2199023255040 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 536870911 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/md1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Comment: root@BigBrain:/ # cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md1 : active raid6 sdc4[0] sdf4[7] sde4[6] sdh4[5] sdg4[4] sdb4[3] sda4[2] sdd4[1]
      46856632320 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [8/8] [UUUUUUUU]

md126 : active raid1 sdc3[0] sdf3[7](S) sde3[6](S) sdh3[5](S) sdg3[4](S) sdb3[3] sda3[2] sdd3[1]
      2095104 blocks super 1.2 [4/4] [UUUU]

md0 : active raid1 sdc2[0] sdf2[7] sde2[6] sdh2[5] sdg2[4] sdb2[3] sda2[2] sdd2[1]
      2095104 blocks super 1.2 [8/8] [UUUUUUUU]

unused devices: <none>